# How do I access a variable in Javascript, set in my codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript

Let me elaborate: I have an ASPX page where the javascript resides, I have three .ascx pages registered there as well. I am trying to use a variable in the javascript that is set in an .ascx page. I am getting an error on the variable "myDate2"
Do I need to put my JavaScript in a .js file in order to use it globally?

sample:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/In/MakePayment1a.ascx" TagPrefix="paymnt" TagName="paymnt" %>
```

javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var dt = <%= this.myDate2 %>
                alert("this is my date :" + dt);

        $(function () {

            var daysValid = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
            var sdate = new Date();
            var edate = new Date();
            edate.setDate(edate.getDate() + 25);

            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                minDate: sdate,
                maxDate: edate,
                beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays,
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "../Images/small_calendar3.jpg",


                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
```

Code behind : from .ascx

```
public DateTime myDate2;
myDate2 = (DateTime)(SummaryDT.Rows[0]["payment_date"]);
```

Comment: "I'm getting an error" isn't very descriptive. Tell us what the exception is an what line it occurs at. Update your question to include it (you should have included it in the beginning).

Comment: my apologies: the error is "ASP in_makepayment_aspx does not contain a definition for 'myDate2' and no extension method 'myDate2'

Comment: Put the exception info in the question, rather than as a comment. This will make it easier for other people to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like myDate2 is a public field of an ascx control which is embedded on the page.  You have to reference it through the control

```
var dt = <%= this.MyControl.myDate2 %>
```

In addition, you probably need quotes.  And you forgot a semicolon.

```
var dt = "<%= this.MyControl.myDate2 %>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access properties from a control directly from the page context (which is what the `this` keyword was doing in your code). But here's what you can do.

Modify your definition in the .ascx.cs page to be like this:

```
public DateTime myDate2 {get; set;}
```

That changes it from a field to a property. Then go to your .aspx page and declare the control on the page like this:

```
<paymnt:paymnt runat="server" id="MyPaymnt" />
```

Then embed it in the JavaScript like this:

```
var dt = '<%= MyPaymnt.myDate2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>';
```

Replace the date format string with whatever is appropriate for your context.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the myDate2 variable in a localStorage variable and then you can find it across your pages without making any global js file for the same

More info on localStorage:

[W3School Explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

[A nice blog on it](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-local-storage-for-javascript/)

Comment: great! would be interested though if any other option apart from global variables or localStorage comes out